# agent lotus: detach file ... and rename them by adding time

Tags: lotus-notes

my lotus agent detachs the files and put them into the one folder
sometimes, the files have the same name so they are overwrited
I would like to rename the file **before** saving it into the folder

```
Set rtitem = curdoc.GetFirstItem( "Body" )
If Not rtitem Is Nothing Then
    If Isarray( rtitem.EmbeddedObjects ) Then 
        Forall o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
            If ( o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then 
                fullpath = path + o.source
                Call o.ExtractFile(fullpath) 
            End If
        End Forall
    End If
End If
```

Could you tell me how i can do it?
thanks a lot 
best regards
dsea

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add the time everytime, then you have to "split" the filename in name and extension before adding the value:

```
Dim strPath as String
Dim strExtension as String
Dim strFullPath as String
Set rtitem = curdoc.GetFirstItem( "Body" )
If Not rtitem Is Nothing Then
    If Isarray( rtitem.EmbeddedObjects ) Then 
      Forall o In rtitem.EmbeddedObjects
          If ( o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then 
              fullpath = path + o.source
              If Instr( fullpath , "." ) > 0 then
                  strPath = StrLeftBack( fullpath , "." )
                  strExtension = "." & StrRightBack( fullpath, "." )
              Else
                  strPath = fullpath
                  strExtension = ""
              End If
              strFullPath = strPath & "-" & Format( Now , "yyyymmdd-hhnnss" ) & strExtension
              Call o.ExtractFile(strFullPath ) 
          End If
      End Forall
  End If
End If
```

Of course you could first "Check" if the file exists, and only add the time- value if it is not unique:

```
Dim strExist as String
...
If ( o.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT ) Then 
    fullpath = path + o.source
    strExist = Dir$( fullPath, 0)
    If strExist <> "" then 'exists
        If Instr( fullpath , "." ) > 0 then
            strPath = StrLeftBack( fullpath , "." )
            strExtension = "." & StrRightBack( fullpath, "." )
        Else
            strPath = fullpath
            strExtension = ""
        End If
        strFullPath = strPath & "-" & Format( Now , "yyyymmdd-hhnnss" ) & strExtension
    Else
        strFullPath = fullpath
    End If
    Call o.ExtractFile(strFullPath ) 
End If
```